# Line break inside procedure's definition with algorithmicx

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, pseudocode

I don't know if this package is the best for my purpose, but I'm using `algorithmicx` (see [here](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) the documentation) to write algorithms (in pseudcode) inside my work.
At now, I've just a problem: input-parameter' names for my procedure are too long, thus text exceeds the box, ruining the layout.

This is the code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm to fetch overlapped objects from input lists.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure {CHECK\_OVERLAP}{$List\_Global\_RE\_To\_Ev\_Objs\_A_k$,$List\_Global\_RE\_To\_Ev\_Objs\_B_k$}
\EndProcedure
\Statex
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

And related output:

[image: Algorithm's body]

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Let me quote from `mathmode`: *LaTeX can break an inline formula only when a relation symbol `(=,<,>,...)` or a binary operation symbol `(+, −, . . .)` exists and at least one of these symbols appears at the outer level of a formula. Thus `$a+b+c$` can be broken across lines, but `${a+b+c}$` not.*

Comment: Hence, is there nothing I can do?!

Comment: Why do you put anything in mathmode? You can also use `textit` or `emph`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I noticed it just now. Anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is very simple: it's enough add a space between commas.

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm to fetch overlapped objects from input lists.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure {CHECK\_OVERLAP}{$List\_Global\_RE\_To\_Ev\_Objs\_A_k$, $List\_Global\_RE\_To\_Ev\_Objs\_B_k$}
\EndProcedure
\Statex
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I'm sorry for such a (stupid) question.
However I hope this answer will save someone else's time.